# Stokes theorem for a donut bounded by a torus

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, stokes-theorem

Is there a reason one cannot apply Stokes theorem $\int_{\Sigma} d \omega = \int_{\partial \Sigma} \omega$, where $\partial \Sigma$ is an orientable, compact manifold with genus $g\geq 1$? For example, could I apply this relation for $\partial \Sigma$ a torus and $\Sigma$ the space contained within the torus (a donut) or the complement of that donut?

Differently stated, must $\Sigma$ be simply connected in order to apply Stokes theorem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can apply Stokes theorem. Cut your torus vertically (so you have two cylinders), then apply Stokes theorem on each piece.

Edit: Doesn't have to be simply connected (recall Green's theorem).